# Why do `while` loops never check user input, whereas `if` statements do?

Tags: ruby

An `if` statement such as:

```
if first_name || first_name.length == 0
  puts "You can't leave the first name blank, try again: "
  first_name = gets
end
```

functions correctly, because it asks for user input, and when tested by not entering any input (including spaces), it prints an error message, followed by prompting for user input, following which,  However, when I attempt to use the same in a `while` loop:

```
while first_name || first_name.length == 0
  puts "You can't leave the first name blank, try again: "
  first_name = gets
end
```

the loop doesn't function correctly.

The loop does the following instead:

• Print the error message above (OK)

• Asks for user input (OK)

• As soon as user input is received, the loop executes once again (Wrong).

It isn't testing the length of the user's (now correct) input, and then allowing the rest of the application to carry out its tasks.

I also tried `unless`, `nil?`, and so on to rectify the loop's error using an `if` statement inside the loop, with no success. I thought the `while` loop would evaluate `first_name` again once the error was corrected, and find that its length was no longer zero, however, that turned out not to be the case.

In Java, to say something isn't equal to something else (in terms of strings, for example), I can use `!` before the variable name. Can I do this in Ruby?

Comment: Please describe what "works" means in reference to the first example.  Be specific: "when (some condition) and then I execute this code, it (whatever it does), which is correct."  Do the same for the other examples.  Be very specific, and remember to explain both what it does, and what it should do.

Comment: Hi Wayne, I've edited the question to make it easier to understand. A little bit of digging further allowed me to figure out why the loop was acting in the manner it did. Apologies for wasting your time (and everyone else's here).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
while first_name.length == 0 do
  puts "You can't leave the first name blank, try again: "
  first_name = gets
end
```

The way `while` cycle works is it evaluates the statement after `while` keyword. If it is `true` then it runs the block. And after that just the same. In your case statement is `first_name || first_name.length == 0` which always will be `true` as first_name is always present. That's the reason it will loop again each time whatever you would input.

Comment: Hi Maxim, what do you mean by "as first_name is always present" ?

Comment: @Paul try `first_name = gets; puts 4 if first_name` whatever you want as input. `first_name` will be string but object is false only if it is `false` or `nil`

Answer (score 1):

I think your condition is just wrong : the condition

```
first_name || first_name.length == 0
```

Will be true if `first_name` is non-nil, this will always be the case since you are setting it to a string.

Answer (score 1):

After some further digging on the Internet, I gave `.chomp` a go, to see what it would do, as I found out that when `gets` is used, it takes your input, but apparently also inserts an `\n` escape sequence, when Enter is pressed, meaning that my loop didn't function as required.

By using `gets.chomp`, in conjunction with `.empty?` I was able to remove this escape sequence from my input, and have the loop function correctly.

Here's the correct code, which prevents an infinite loop:

```
first_name = gets.chomp

while first_name.empty? do

  puts "You can't leave the first name blank, try again: "
  first_name = gets.chomp

end
```